# Spring Boot:Different configurations for running locally vs deployed Jar?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle

So I have a spring boot app that is deployed on Amazon Web Services using the jar,I also run the program locally using "Boot Run" in IntelliJ for testing 
There are just two things I want to change in how my program runs when I run it with bootrun locally and when its deployed from a jar in the cloud.

In my app.properties there is 4 properties I set that are related to storing sessin data in a redis cluster and I have one @Bean in a java @Configuration class that is related to configuring redis.How can I set it so that when I run locally Spring ignores those 4 properties and java beans but includes them when I deploy?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Spring profiles for this. You can override properties and load classes conditionally using a specific profile.

Your `application.properties` file is loaded by default by the `default` profile. Let's say you want to override your Redis configuration enties. Simply add to the resources folder a file called `application-redis.properties` and write the properties that you want to override. Then run your application with the parameter `--spring.profiles.active=redis` on the command line (if you were using maven it would be `-Dspring.profiles.active=redis`, I don't know if that's the case with Gradle), or add to your `application.properties` the line `spring.profiles.active=redis` to avoid the argument. This also works if you build your jar.

Example:

```
#application.properties

some.config=some-value

#application-redis.properties

#this value takes precedence if you run with the profile "redis" active
some.config=other-value
```

Then, to load a specific `@Configuration` class (or any other spring injected class) you add the `@Profile` annotation like:

```
@Profile("redis")
@Configuration
public class SomeConfigurationClass {
  //...
}
```

Then this Configuration class will only load if you run the application with the "redis" active profile. You can read the documentation for more info:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html

Comment: Just to add to this. You can have multiple application-{profile}.properties files. Each of them can have unique, profile related, values and settings.

Comment: Yes, as per @MikhailKholodkov comment, check this page in the documentation... https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html